# How do I access a private class variable when calling a method statically?

Tags: php

If I have:

```
<?php
class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass{
  private $access_code = 'TX9999';

  private static function SomeMethod(){

  }
}

?>
```

And do

```
<?
self::SomeMethod();
?>
```

how do I correctly access `$access_code` in `::SomeMethod()`

More Info

What Im actually facing is more complex.

I have a class with methods that are and must remain static.
I know how to call other methods using self.

However across the class I have things that would ordinarily make sense as constants and variables.

I realise that I haven't got an instance in the normal way and am looking for away to share variables between some of the static methods of the class, some are volatile, some fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do what you want; it creates an instance of itself first before being able to access the private instance variable `$access_code`.

```
$o = new self;
echo $o->access_code;
```

---

If you want a class variable instead of instance variable, you have to declare the `$access_code` like this:

```
private static $access_code = 'TX9999';
```

Then call it from the static method like this:

```
private static function SomeMethod()
{
    echo self::$access_code;
}
```

Btw, you can't call `::SomeMethod()` from outside the class. In order to do that, you need to make it `public`:

```
public static function SomeMethod() { ... }
```

Comment: The question was from within a method in the class... not outside the class.

Comment: @Brian yeah, but the method is static so by itself it can't access the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a static method and your variable is not, you'd need an instance. I'd suggest, if that value won't change, you have as such:

```
<?php
class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass{
  private static $access_code = 'TX9999';

  private static function SomeMethod(){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually (not 100 % sure for PHP) you need to have an instance of your class to access its variables.

Second possibility is to make the variable static too.

Examples:

1.

```
<?php
class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass{
  public $access_code = 'TX9999';

  public static function SomeMethod() {
     SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
     echo sc.access_code;
  }
}
```

2.

```
<?php
class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass{
  public static $access_code = 'TX9999';

  public static function SomeMethod() {
     // no need for SomeClass, because your in the same class, but if you want to use it directly from outside the class
     echo SomeClass.access_code;
  }
}
?>
```

btw: I changed private to public

ps: not sure if this is php compatible :)

Answer (score 0):

First off,

```
<?
SomeClass::SomeMethod();
?>
```

Will fail. You declared it as private. This means, even if declared static, it can only be called within your class. Not outside. Change it to `protected` or `public`.

Also,

You cannot call to `$access_code` from within a static method unless you declare it as static. Static methods do not have insight into `$this`. They can access constants and `self` but what they are accessing must be static.

Comment: It would be called from within class, Ive simplified quite a lot to get the point across

Comment: But,  calling `SomeClass::SomeMethod();` is considered external. Although `$access_code` is private, and you are calling it from a static method, it must also be `private static`

Answer (score 0):

I belive you need to use the `self` keyword, so you would access it in your function like this:

```
private static function SomeMethod(){
   return self::$access_code;
}
```

EDIT: $access_code would need to be declared as static as well for this to work.

Comment: This would fail with `PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: SomeClass::$access_code`